# No puedo retornar el token

Tags: php, api, tokens

Estoy trabajando con una API que actualiza un token cada 24hs. El problema es que no puedo retornar ese token para utilizarlo en otras peticiones de la API y valor que obtengo en `NULL`.

**-- ACTUALIZADO**

Pude acceder al headers y tomar token y la respuesta es `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Auth-Token X-Auth-Token: XXXXXXXXXXsBRncbdt9A0aguvJOpOut3vPJ7wLXXXX= Cache-Control`.

Usando `$token = explode(":", $response);` puedo acceder al token pero de esta manera: `XXXXXXXXXXsBRncbdt9A0aguvJOpOut3vPJ7wLXXXX= Cache-Control` y no logro quitar los datos que están por demás.

El resultado debería ser: `XXXXXXXXXXsBRncbdt9A0aguvJOpOut3vPJ7wLXXXX=`

```
<?php

$username = XXXXXXXXXX;
$password = XXXXXXXXXX;

$url = 'https://api.remarkets.primary.com.ar/auth/getToken';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// SOLUCION -------

$data = json_encode($response);

$explode = explode(":", $data);
$token = substr($explode[9], 0, -17);

echo $token;

?>
```

Documentación: https://apihub.primary.com.ar/assets/docs/Primary-API.pdf

Dejo el código y agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿Hay alguna documentación que te indique ese proceso?

Comment: Me olvide de compartirla, ya edite la publicación.

Comment: Excelente, según veo, parece que está bien, intenta realizar la misma petición usando `Postman` y mira si te da algún resultado favorable.

Comment: Si si, trabaje con Postman, pero lo estoy pasando para obtener el token en una variable ya que el token dura solo 24hs

Comment: Entonces con Postman pinta bien, ¡excelente! queda descartada la idea de mal input en usuario y/o contraseña. ¿Has intentado quitar el espacio en blanco luego de los dos puntos?

Comment: Si si, ya he intentado lo que me dices, pero si, en Postman no tengo inconvenientes

Comment: La respuesta va ABAJO en el campo TU Respuesta, por favor. No se necesita editar el título